# Shapefile calculation error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

Tags: shapefile, r, error, sf

I'm trying to identify which of two regions within a shapefile specific spatial points lie. To this I used [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282750/identify-polygon-containing-point-with-r-sf-package/343477#343477) code.

This worked well but I ended with a lot of NAs because my 1/3 of my points are slightly outside the shapefile boundaries.

I ended up creating a new shape file with a buffer around the two regions. However, for some reason, despite the shape files have the same class columns as the old shapefile etc, it does not run and I get this error

```
map = read_sf("OSPAR23_buf1.shp")
pnts <- subset(SENT, select=c(Longitude, Latitude, ID))

pnts_sf <- st_as_sf(pnts, coords = c('Longitude', 'Latitude'), crs = st_crs(map))

pnts <- pnts_sf %>% mutate(
  intersection = as.integer(st_intersects(geometry, map)),
  OSPAR = if_else(is.na(intersection), '', map$Region[intersection]))
```

Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

I then tried to create a buffer around the pnts file using this code taken from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292327/creating-buffers-around-points-and-merging-with-spatialpolygonsdataframe-to-crea) post

```
pnts_sf_buf = st_buffer(pnts_sf, 0.25)
```

And run the previous code with the maps that had worked previously. But I get the same error.

There does not seem to be any obvious difference between the shape files that worked and those that don't, and I really can't figure out why this isn't working.

A subset of my data is below. A zipfile of the old shapefile that worked is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8seusuz4d38eqzn/OSPAR_II_III.zip?dl=0). The new shapefile that gives the error is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p72wa14u1uiuiin/OSPAR23_buf1.zip?dl=0)

```
structure(list(Longitude = c(-3.55322138, -4.694794872, -6.116016097, 
-4.520111046, -0.910337034, -3.408259063), Latitude = c(50.43247257, 
50.34775167, 57.13215105, 51.73420664, 50.78851095, 54.27026104
), ID = 1:6), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```